# List oracle stored procedures name with original case

Tags: oracle

How can I list all stored procedures/arguments of a package with their original name.

When I do the following all names are in uppercase:

```
SELECT object_name, argument_name, in_out, data_type FROM All_arguments;
```

Is there a way the find the original name (original case).
Say when I create a stored procedure with the name "getMyStoredProcedure", I would like the get the name in that case.

Comment: Keep your source - oracle by default creates objects using upper case characters. So a phrase example: 'create or replace'  becomes 'CREATE OR REPLACE'.  In other words lower case characters get changed forever. You cannot get them back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, Oracle identifiers are case-insensitive.  Identifiers are automatically converted to upper case in the data dictionary.

You can prevent that upper casing by choosing to use case-sensitive identifiers which requires that you enclose the identifiers in double-quotes.  If you

```
CREATE PROCEDURE "myCamelCaseProc"
...
```

the procedure name will remain `myCamelCaseProc` in the data dictionary.  If you do that, however, you would need to enclose the identifier in double-quotes every time you reference it and you would have to get the casing correct every time.  That is generally a poor architectural choice to make-- future developers will likely curse your name when they find themselves trying to read code that is littered with double-quotes and where identifiers are unexpectedly case-sensitive.

Comment: I read about that before, but I was wondering how PL/SQL Developer was able to list them in the right case when to do View Spec & Body. It probably parse the package body to list them.